# Cannot edit a file as root if ~/.authinfo.gpg file exists

Tags: gnus, sudo, root

I got `~/.authinfo.gpg` to store my multiple email accounts for `gnus`, but if `~/.authinfo.gpg` exists, the `tramp` won't work. It will always say:

```
Decrypting /home/chz/.authinfo.gpg...done
```

Emacs won't even load the file into Emacs. If I remove that file, the `tramp` will work fine and `gnus` will not work as I want.

The `tramp` configuration is like [this page](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/21/edit-files-as-root/) or [this page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SudoSave)(I've tried several versions, defun, defadvice, etc.), and the `~/.authinfo.gpg` file contains lines of my emails accounts and `machine localhost port sudo login root password my-password` suggested by [this page](https://github.com/m00natic/m00natic.github.com/blob/master/org/emacs/emacs-wiki.org#dont-ask-for-sudo-or-ssh-passwords) to edit file as root.

Even I don't use the `tramp` configuration mentioned above, just use `C-x C-f /sudo::/etc/hosts`, after I finished typing the second `:`, `Decrypting /home/chz/.authinfo.gpg...done` will automatically exist in minibuffer and stuck  Emacs, then I have to `C-g`...

So how can I use edit-as-root and gnus at the same time?

Can I use other ways other than ~/.authinfo.gpg to store account info for my multiple emails accounts so edit-as-root will work too?

===============================================

Update:

After testing my init.el piece by piece, it turned out that the `which-function-mode` and `projectile` don't work with tramp very well, I have to disable them when using tramp.

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in `emacs -q`? If not, please post the part of your `.emacs` that would allow someone else to reproduce the problem. Which version of Emacs are you running?

Comment: I have a similar configuration and it works for me (tested again with Emacs 24.4 and 25.0.50). The only difference is the host name used in `~/.authinfo.gpg`: `machine hostname port sudo login root password my-password` Note that I have used `hostname` (which is the real host name) instead of `localhost`.

Comment: @Gilles After `emacs -q`, `M-x load-file /path/to/init-gnus.el`, the `C-x C-f /sudo::/etc/hosts` works fine, and `M-x gnus` works as expected too. I guess I have to test my init.el piece by piece again.

Comment: @Gilles `(which-function-mode 1)` and `projectile` don't get along with tramp after I tested my init.el piece by piece. Disabling `which-function-mode` and `projectile-global-mode` when using tramp to solve this problem.

Comment: Nice progress. Please update your question, ideally with a minimal `init.el` that exhibits the problem. And tell us which Emacs version you're running.

Comment: This issue is also related to emacs-eclim, check out [here](https://github.com/emacs-eclim/emacs-eclim/issues/15) for details.